# How do I get integrated Flask-Bootstrap to work with my Flask Project?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, flask-bootstrap

I have the flask-bootstrap already installed and imported into my project through a virtualenv. I am trying to initiate the 'base.html' template that comes with the flask-bootstrap package but when I load my project, the website doesn't display any sign of bootstrap. How do I solve this?
Below is how I imported the flask_bootstrap package.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
manager = Manager(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Also, this is the code I am trying to initiate the package from:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Flasky</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

But this is the result I get:

[flasky-sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRjN2.png)

Comment: You only have a Navbar and it sure looks like it has some bootstrap default styling on it (the page header class even positions the text properly). What else were you expecting to see?

Comment: Agree with @danidee here. This appears to be expected output, for the most part (albeit I thought "navbar-inverse" was black), but you've got `li` items rendering as a menu bar...that counts as bootstrap. Expand the example a bit and you should be able to get better style, use the [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Also--this may be fine, but every example I've ever seen for `data-target` for your first `button` element is usually an ID, not a class.

Comment: @danidee I'm expecting to see an inverse navbar and the "Hello Evans!" is expected to be below the navbar

Comment: @PJSantoro Yea! I was expecting a black navbar... Also with the proper glyphicon